# stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in addSelect Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got query builder like this
$mahasiswa=DB::table('MSMHS')->

```
select('nimhsMSMHS','noktpMSMHS','nmmhsMSMHS','tahunMSMHS','kdfakMSMHS','kdjurMSMHS','kdjekMSMHS','tplhrMSMHS','tglhrMSMHS','telhpMSMHS','staklMSMHS','emailMSMHS')
       ->addSelect(['sksMSMHS' => function($query){
            $query->select('SKSTTHSIPK')
            ->from('HSIPK')
            ->whereColumn('NIMHSHSIPK','nimhsMSMHS')
            ->orderBy('THSMSHSIPK','DESC')
            ->limit(1);
        }])
        ->where('MSMHS.staklMSMHS','A')
        ->where('MSMHS.nimhsMSMHS','152017015')
        ->get();
```

And got error

> stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

What i missing here?

Comment: I'm seeing a fair number of questions about this on SO already: [presumably you already found all of those, too](/help/how-to-ask), can you explain how none of those solved your problem?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i try it like not using array in addSelect, but still not solve my problem

Comment: Don't tell "me", tell everyone by updating your post to talk about what you already searched and found, the various things you tried based on those findings, and what the result of that was.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the ->get() before the ->addSelect